# Unit Testing dynamic loading of javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing JavaScript tests in Jasmine for a method that dynamically load jQuery if not present or the version loaded is an earlier version that what the plugin requires. What is needed is to test a couple of different scenarios.

- No library exists
- An earlier version exists, so is upgraded
- A new version is specified (options)
- etc

The issue is that the test adds a version of jQuery to the page, so this effects/interferes with later tests. Is there any way to reload the page or remove added javascript?

**Solution**

I've found a work around for testing. The code to check if JQuery is loaded is:

```
if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){ [load JQuery]; }
```

In the Jasmin `afterEach` method:

```
jQuery = undefined;
```

It doesn't actually remove the dynamically loaded library, but the method being tested doesn't see it.

Comment: How do you "load jquery" ? Do you load the file content and eval it yourself ? Would it be acceptable to eval it in a different context than the browser's window ?

Comment: Maybe I am miss-reading your question but, if jQuery is not being properly managed/namespaced in test, wouldn't you be concerned there would be global pollution in production as well?

Comment: Isn't jQuery normally loaded into it's own namespace jQuery (<link> in the page). The method is to either load a newer version (if already loaded) or load it if it doesn't exist. The behavior of the method is to mimic this behavior. It's not polluting any more than is normal (it is loaded with .noConflict()).